# Finding the base in an exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I'm trying to solve for $b$ in what seems like a very simple exponential equation:
$b^{4.89}=1 182 795 699$

I know that $y=\log_b x$ is equivalent to $b^y=x$ but I don't know how that helps me to isolate $b$. I looked for the solution in WolframAlpha and it gives me $b=71.68$, but it won't show a step-by-step solution.

I would appreciate a lot if you could tell me how to solve this equation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$b^{4.89}=1 182 795 699$$
Taking natural $\log$ on both sides,
$$\log b^{4.89}=\log1 182 795 699$$
$$4.89\log b=\log1 182 795 699$$
$$\log b=\frac{\log(1 182 795 699)}{4.89}$$
$$b=e^{\frac{\log(1 182 795 699)}{4.89}}$$

Answer (score 3):

When you learn logs don't forget everything you know about roots!

$b^{4.89}=1 182 795 699$

So $(b^{4.89})^{\frac 1{4.89}} = 1,182,795,699^{\frac 1{4.89}}$

So $b =  1,182,795,699^{\frac 1{4.89}}=71.680456772641838989153714527019$

Answer (score 0):

$$b^{4.89}=1 182 795 699$$
It is also equal to
$$b^{489/100}=1182795699$$
Hence,
$$b=1182795699^{100/489}$$